# Resolving non-content git merge conflicts with "ours"

Tags: git, merge

When merging one branch into another with 'git merge some_branch -Srecursive -Xours', I sometimes get rename/delete, modify/delete, and rename/rename conflicts. I would've thought these conflicts could be handled by the -Xours option, but apparently it only handles content conflicts.

I'd like to resolve all the above conflicts in favor of HEAD in the merge command - is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify - if you run `git merge -X ours`, there will still be merge conflicts?

Comment: It's `-s`, not `-S`; `-S` is for GPG-signing the commit.  I assume that's just a typo here.  The recursive merge strategy is the default anyway, so it should make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `-X` applies only to content conflicts.

I think—I have not re-checked any of this—that a rename/delete conflict results in the file being left behind (under its new name), regardless of which branch renamed it and which deleted it.  So here you must manually `git rm` files that are no longer in `HEAD` but are in `MERGE_HEAD`, otherwise `git add` them to resolve the conflict.

A modify/delete is handled the same way, so here you would manually `git rm` or `git add` it it the same way.

A rename/rename conflict is probably (I have not come across it myself) resolved in favor of the `HEAD` rename, so all you need to do here is `git add` the file under the new name.

Note that you can do all this programmatically by reading the output of `git ls-files --stage`.  For file name safety, you may want to use `-z` as well (but then you need to use bash or Python or some other language that can handle the NUL bytes).